# No Body Data Being Passed using .NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, greasemonkey, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm migrating my code from .NET to .NET Core 6 and have hit a brick wall and googling doesn't seem to have helped so any advice, pointers will be welcome.

All of this works in .NET so it's clearly my understanding of how to migrate the API.

I am using a greasemonkey script to scrape some data and pass it to my site.

```
function sendHome() {
    console.log(window.eval('window.PA_intel'));
    GM.xmlHttpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:7223/api/Parsing/Any",
        data: "{ Data: '" + JSON.stringify(window.eval('window.PA_intel')) + "', Type: 'Intel'}",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        onload: function (response) { console.log(response); toastr["success"]("Intel sent home!", "Phoenix"); },
        onerror: function (reponse) {console.log("error: ", reponse)},
    });

}
```

This grabs the data from a page an pushes it to an API route that is waiting on api/Parsing/Any

The debug and postman can trigger the API controller so I know the routing works but the body (Data and Type from the GM script) isn't coming with it.

I have a defined model to receive the data

```
    public class ParseData
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

and my controller is set up to expect it, but in .NET CORE 6 it's just coming up null

```
    [Route("api/Parsing/")]
    public class ParsingAPIController : Controller
    {

        [Route("Any")]
        public List<ParseResult> ParseAny(ParseData parseData)
        //public List<ParseResult> ParseAny(string Data, string Type)

        {
```

As I said the routing is being triggered but the parseData object is null and if I inpsect ParseAny to see what has been sent, I get an error with null body.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: try passing `data` as a javascript object instead of a string

Comment: It looks like the content you're passing isn't actually valid JSON - it's using `'` instead of `"` for the values, and you don't have quotes around Type or Data. Try using definitely-valid JSON in conjunction with `FromBody`.

Comment: The GM script does work with .NET which is confusing however I have amended the script to only pass in the JSON, in addition I've added [FromBody] and accept it into one string to remove anything else that may be causing the issue. Unfortunately, the body is still null.

Comment: Best way is to build in Net and target the core version.  Are you building on same machine that you are deploying.  May need to install runtime version of Core on target machine.  Are you building/running on same machine that worked?

Comment: yeah, I'm doing all my testing on the same machine. I'll give that a go and see if I can spot the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix ajax data

```
...
data: JSON.stringify({ Data: window.eval('window.PA_intel'), Type: 'Intel'}),
...
```

and an action header

```
     [Route("Any")]
     public List<ParseResult> ParseAny([FromBody]ParseData parseData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the tag [FromBody] with the ParseData parameter.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, it destroys my ability to use the model properly but I tried it before posting and it didn't work. The problem seems to be the body is null when it gets to the controller but it's definitely populated when it leaves the GM script. Fiddler has confirmed this and I've used Post Man to create my own tests too

Comment: Try using this format with the data variable JSON.stringify({ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" })

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to do 2 things:

1. Add [ParseBody] to your parameter.
2. Add [HttpPost] as annotation to your method so that it accepts post requests and gets the post body in the request. Finally your code should be like below:

   ```
    [Route("api/Parsing/")]
    public class ParsingAPIController : Controller
    {

        [Route("Any")]
        [HttpPost]
        public List<ParseResult> ParseAny([FromBody]ParseData parseData)
        {
   ```